# Pandas: resample a dataframe to match a DatetimeIndex of a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, resampling, pandas-resample

I have a two time series in separate `pandas.dataframe`, the first one - `series1` has less entries and different start datatime from the second - `series2`:

```
index1 = pd.date_range(start='2020-06-16 23:16:00', end='2020-06-16 23:40:30', freq='1T')
series1 = pd.Series(range(len(index1)), index=index1)
index2 = pd.date_range('2020-06-16 23:15:00', end='2020-06-16 23:50:30', freq='30S')
series2 = pd.Series(range(len(index2)), index=index2)
```

How can I resample series2 to match the `DatetimeIndex` of `series1`?

Comment: What operation you want to do when resampling? doing a `mean`, get the `min`, `max`, ...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas-series-reindex):

```
series2.reindex(series1.index)
```

Output:

```
2020-06-16 23:16:00     2
2020-06-16 23:17:00     4
2020-06-16 23:18:00     6
2020-06-16 23:19:00     8
2020-06-16 23:20:00    10
2020-06-16 23:21:00    12
2020-06-16 23:22:00    14
2020-06-16 23:23:00    16
2020-06-16 23:24:00    18
2020-06-16 23:25:00    20
2020-06-16 23:26:00    22
2020-06-16 23:27:00    24
2020-06-16 23:28:00    26
2020-06-16 23:29:00    28
2020-06-16 23:30:00    30
2020-06-16 23:31:00    32
2020-06-16 23:32:00    34
2020-06-16 23:33:00    36
2020-06-16 23:34:00    38
2020-06-16 23:35:00    40
2020-06-16 23:36:00    42
2020-06-16 23:37:00    44
2020-06-16 23:38:00    46
2020-06-16 23:39:00    48
2020-06-16 23:40:00    50
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `reindex` is the best for this case :) +1

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: @Tobbey, one of your series has multiple indexes.  You can't use `reindex` with duplicate index labels.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't a simple resample yield the results are looking for?

```
series2.resample('T').first()
```

If your goal is to merge the resampled timestamp back to the first dataset, you could do that as follows:

```
dt_map = {}
for group_label, group_series in series2.resample('T'):
    dt_map.update({x:group_label for x in group_series.index})

# Overwrite the index
series2.index = series2.index.map(dt_map)
```

Note: If you want to perform an aggregate function, stick with the first option.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, this is what you need:

```
series2[series2.index.isin(series1.index)]
```

Comment: Nice idea! But in this solution I should first make sure that the two time series are synchronized... still a good solution - thanks!

Comment: It's the same result as @scottboston.  Nothing particularly wrong with this, but syntax is not as simple.